# Why are zero length spaces being returned from a Union All against an empty table in SQL Server 2005 but not SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Supporting an existing VB6 app with a SQL Server 2005 back end and we're migrating our database server to SQL Server 2012. Created a backup of the production database and restored it into a dev database on both servers. Other than the server version the databases are identical and the Compatibility Level is still set to 90 (SQL Server 2005).

When I run a query on SQL Server 2005, similar to the example below, a string is returned with extra spaces for any blank fields. If I run the same query on SQL Server 2012 there are no extra spaces being returned. As far as I can tell it seems to be an issue with doing a `UNION ALL` against a table with no records and a char data type but I wanted to ask anyway.

For the below example you'd need to create a table with one `NOT NULL`, `Char(2)` column named `Unit6`. Leave the table empty with no records once created.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTest](
    [Unit6] [char](2) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I run the following query I receive two different results depending on the server version:

```
SELECT 
   Unit5, Unit6,
   LEN(Unit6) as Len_Unit6, 
   '--|' + Unit6 + '|--' as Spanner
FROM
   (SELECT      
       '13' as Unit5,
       '' as Unit6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      
        '',
        Unit6 
    FROM tblTest) as MyData
```

Results on SQL Server 2005

[image: SQL 2005 Results]

Results on SQL Server 2012

[image: SQL 2012 Results]

Hopefully you can see the Spanner column shows two spaces when run on 2005 vs zero spaces when run on 2012.

This is a major issue as the app runs queries similar to the above example and then later uses string functions to cut up a single string for database inserts and updates. Without the spaces which are being included on SQL Server 2005 the string functions are carving up the wrong pieces which causes any inserts or updates to fail.

Any information would be most helpful. Thank you!

Server Versions

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (Intel X86) 
Nov 24 2008 13:01:59 
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3393.0 (X64) 
Oct 25 2013 19:04:40 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

Comment: Try to put to spaces at that '' as Unit6. Union ill try to return a varchar(n) if ehe finds a string with n chars

Comment: @jean that doesn't reproduce the problem. Making that change would return two spaces in the spanner without adding a UNION.

Comment: Is there a collation difference between the two servers? There is likely an implicit conversion occurring which casts your first `select ''` to a `char(2)` based on the schema of the second select which references `tblTest`

Comment: @NathanSkerl Checked it out and both servers have a Server Collation of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS but thanks for the thought.

Comment: It could also be a collation difference at the column level, but in any case I would look for the `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` operation in the execution plan on the offending server to rule it out

Comment: I ran my test query including the actual execution plan. See six operations SELECT, Compute Scalar, Concatenation, Constant Scan, Compute Scalar (again) and finally Table Scan. I'd be happy to provide more details if required.

Comment: If you hover over the operations you should see detail in popup. There is where you will find the Convert_Implicit.  See:  http://www.brentozar.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Implicit-Conversion-1.jpg

Comment: Not sure if it's only under the Predicate section but I don't see it in the detail of any operations. Most of the operations have an Output List, one also had a Values section and another has an Object section. None of them seem to have a CONVERT_IMPLICIT statement. Checked both servers.

Comment: Have you tried an explicit cast?  `'--|' + cast(Unit6 as varchar) + '|--' as Spanner`

Comment: Tried out the explicit cast and got the same results. 2 space span on the 2005 server and no span on 2012 server.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ANSI_PADDING setting:

> Controls the way the column stores values shorter than the defined size of the column, and the way the column stores values that have trailing blanks in char, varchar, binary, and varbinary data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx

---

I just tried on both SQL Server 2005 and 2012 and I don't get those results:

```
Unit5 Unit6 Len_Unit6   Spanner
----- ----- ----------- --------
13          0           --||--

(1 row(s) affected)


Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (Intel X86) 
    Dec 10 2010 10:56:29 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

(1 row(s) affected)


Unit5 Unit6 Len_Unit6   Spanner
----- ----- ----------- --------
13          0           --||--

(1 row(s) affected)


Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3349.0 (X64) 
    Mar  8 2013 17:33:56 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I'm using two exact copies of the database so the ANSI Padding Status for all columns in all tables are identical.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter when the column is NOT NULL anyway, it should always be padded to the length of the column.

Comment: I'm not sure how should always be but I'd expect it would be consistent between server versions. No idea why you didn't see the same results.

Comment: idk either, I haven't found a setting yet that gives me the results you're seeing.

Comment: what's really weird is that even your query results say len(unit6) is 0, but something is still inside the spanner

Comment: Seems to me that the issue is performing a UNION of two records where a field in one contains an empty string ('') and the same field in the other is a selected char(x) field from a database with no records. Still not sure why it would work differently between the two SQL versions.

Comment: You've nailed it on the weirdness. I was first trying to track this down by checking field lengths. How in the heck you can have a zero length field which shows two spaces when you concatenate is beyond me.

Comment: I've added the @@Version information for both servers to the tail end of my original post. Should have included them initially as you did.

Comment: The len makes sense, in that the length of an empty char(2) is still 0, `select len(cast('' as char(2)))`, `datalength` will tell the truth, but what is causing the char(2) cast in the subquery?? I am unable to reproduce

Comment: @NathanSkerl I'm not sure but it seems to have something to do with the char(2) column in the empty table used for the 2nd part of the Union. If I change Unit6 in the 2nd query to an empty string '' then I don't see the issue.

Comment: Note, that LEN ignores trailing spaces. `LEN(' ') = 0`. That's normal. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx the char(2) should be converted to varchar. Maybe a 2005 bug? Unlikely.